# OSX Second monitor/display background

Tags: snow-leopard, display, graphics

Is it possible to change the display default image on a second display connected to an Apple running OSX 10.6. ? I can see all the display options for the desktop, but the 2nd display has the Apple Desktop picture 'Apple/Nature/Aurora as a default.  The only way I can find of changing this is to select mirroring on displays and then choose an alternative, which will display on both screens.  Turn mirroring off then 'Aurora' returns, but the desktop will reflect the new change.
kind regards
Ric

Comment: Answer doesn't work.  I can bring up the display manager for that screen, select the image, and nothing happens.

Answer (score 21):

@Rick - With Mirroring turned off, when you open System Preferences and click Desktop & Screen Saver, you should see a window open in each display that allows you to select a distinct background image for each display.

[Mac 101: Change your desktop](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2478)

Comment: Yup, that'd be the way

Comment: Thank you!! I'm a teacher displaying to a screen on the other side of my room through a LCD projector, and the previous background made seeing the cursor at that distance almost impossible. Thank you, Thank you!!

Comment: How can you change the second display's background without having a second screen connected at that very moment?